# Outlook Journal Entries using EWS / programmatically

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Is there a way to get the Outlook Journal entries programmatically? I am using EWS managed api for C# for other Exchange communication but the API does not have anything to handle Journals directly.
Is there a way to handle Journals using EWS? If not, what are other options?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup the Journal, so that it will send all Mails to a specific user. Then you can connect to the EWS using that users credentials and work with all entries there. I don't know if that is best practise.

Answer (score -1):

Exchange Web Services .NET works directly with Journals:

[Create Journal](http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/createjournal.html)
[Find Journal](http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/findjournal.html)

Comment: That is not EWS but Independentsoft which is a 3rd party product. There is no Journal Class in the EWS API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220535(v=exchg.80).aspx